# ng-serve failed with yarn as package manager

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package-managers, yarnpkg

I set `yarn` as package manager for `angular-cli`, when I run `ng new my-app` it finishes successfully

```
Installing packages for tooling via yarn.
Installed packages for tooling via yarn.
```

but when I run `ng-serve` I get the following error message:

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hadi\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hadi\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hadi\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\styles.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I have `angular-clie` version 1.4.4 and `yarn` version 1.1.0

Comment: try yarn start instead of ng serve to run development project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do following steps :

```
npm install -g yarn
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

run project using

```
yarn start
```

Comment: Great, but now ng set is deprecated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999229/angular-cli-with-yarn