# Angular CLI with yarn

Tags: angular, yarnpkg

How to change package manager for Angular Cli v6.0.3 to yarn?
I tried:

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

But Angular says:

> get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```

Comment: Seems in version 8, 'set' comes back with an error.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: With yarn v3 I'm getting the following error: `throw new Error(`Cannot locate the 'node_modules' directory.`);`

Answer (score 14):

You can set global configuration using

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```

If you want to set the package manager for a particular project then go to the root directory of the project and use the following command

```
ng config cli.packageManager yarn
```

Answer (score 7):

I. **Global configuration**

```
 ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```

II. **For a particular project**

```
 ng config cli.packageManager yarn
```

Or you can add it directly in **angular.json** like this :

```
   "cli": {
 
      "packageManager": "yarn"

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To ng update using yarn you can also run:

`ng update --packageManager=yarn`

`ng update --all --packageManager=yarn`

Answer (score 3):

you hav to update package manager from npm to yarn.

```
ng config --global packageManager=yarn
```

if you need back yarn to npm then

```
ng config --global packageManager=npm
```

Comment: As of `6.0.0` this approach is deprecated in favor of `ng config`.